# Unable to open eclipse Ganymede IDE

Tags: eclipse

[image]Hi,
i am unable to open Eclipse Ganymede IDE..
It is displaying the message attached with this post..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the above mentioned error by editing the eclipse.ini file available at " ../eclipse/eclilpse/eclipse.ini.

Changes need to be done carefully..

> --launcher.XXMaxPermSize 256m
>   -vmargs
>   -Xms**1024**m
>   -Xmx**1024**m

I  have changed the two 1024 values to the max permitted i.e.256m as follows.

> --launcher.XXMaxPermSize 256m
>   -vmargs
>   -Xms**256**m
>   -Xmx**256**m

Comment: That -Xmx value may be too small to be practical.  You should Accept your answer if the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, this often means something wrong in your eclipse.ini file.

try change every part of this

> ... Eclipse\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox ...

into this

> ... Eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox ...

Comment: Not able to get what you suggested me to do.. Anyway it helped me to fix the issue and find the solution. Thank you Rangi